# Connecting with mysql using android

Tags: php, android, mysql, database, json

I am trying to use live database through android. For that I am following the link below:

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/

But i can't figure out what should be the values of the following in localhost and in live database?

```
define('DB_USER', "root"); // db user
define('DB_PASSWORD', "mypassword"); // db password
define('DB_DATABASE', "?????"); // database name
define('DB_SERVER', "?????"); // db server
```

And I am getting

```
 json end of input at character 0 of
```

which I suppose is due to the incorrect values of above. Also it would be good to check my username and password again. How is that done? Thank you for your time..

Comment: Connecting directly to MySQL from a mobile app is almost always the worst possible idea. Are you sure you want to do this?

Comment: you mean, i should use emulator??

Comment: I mean you shouldn't have your MySQL port 3306 flapping in the breeze for anyone on the public internet to connect to. It's extremely risky to do that. Instead you should create an application layer around your database that handles authentication, data validation, and connects to the MySQL server in a secure way. It's more work, but it's more reliable, especially if it's a simple JSON API using HTTPS. Maintaining a MySQL connection on a mobile device is nearly impossible.

Comment: did you see the link that i have provided? i am using api. I am not quite sure if it's good. Can you guide me? Thanks in advance

Comment: @tadman what is db_database and db_server for lamp in ubuntu? Default values??

Comment: That code you link to uses the antiquated `mysql_query` interface and is absolutely riddled with [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). **DO NOT** use this code under any circumstances. Throw it in the trash and find something else. If you deploy this on a production application, you will end up in serious trouble eventually.

Comment: thank you :-) Can you give me proper link??

Comment: @Nabin you are asking us about your server configuration. DB_SERVER is whatever your server name is, and DB_DATABASE is whatever your database name is. If you have a database you should know it. if you dont have one thats the first problem...

Comment: If you're going to write a layer like this, start with a [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) and build up from there. That'll make it far easier to build a safe, secure application that can handle your present and future needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
define('DB_USER', "root"); // db user
define('DB_PASSWORD', "mypassword"); // db password
define('DB_DATABASE', "?????"); // database name
define('DB_SERVER', "?????"); // db server
```

So the values you should insert here would be:

```
define('DB_USER', "root"); // db user
define('DB_PASSWORD', ""); // db password
define('DB_DATABASE', "android"); // database name
define('DB_SERVER', "localhost"); // db server
```

This is going be default generic values, root with no password, localhost, and then the name of the database that contains your tables.

Using the mySQL part will leave some pretty big holes for hackers, but when it comes to learning the basics it should be alright. I would optimize it a lot more by using mySQLI which will leave you with some work to do but will work way more efficiently.

Comment: `mysqli` is arguably better than the trashy `mysql_query` code in there, but if you're going to re-write, PDO is even better still.

Comment: I agree PDO is the best, but for someone who is just beginning the conversion from mysql to mysqli is a great start. Then if you feel the need convert from mysqli to PDO.

Comment: PDO isn't hard to learn, [there's many great tutorials](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/), and is simpler to use than `mysqli`. There's no need for the intermediate step, I'd argue it adds confusion. Even better is using [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/)
or [Propel](http://propelorm.org/) rather than writing queries by hand.